How can modify my redefinition of `\item` to be compatible with tagging-pdf?
I have a horizontal list environment mylist created with expl3 with key=val support based on code from the shortlst package. The environment works similarly to the tasks or enumerate* environment from the enumitem package, it works OK and compiles without errors when using \DocumentMetadata, but the structure created is not correct.
In order for it to work as I want the command \item has the form (in terms of ltcmd/xparse) \item{ D() s o o }, but I have not been able to use \RenewDocumentCommand  (does not work in this case) and I have had to make a cascade of functions using \cs_new_protected... and \peek_meaning:NTF.
The \item and \item[opt] commands work in the usual way, and the optionals arguments I have added are:

\item(join): It is the first optional argument and joins columns, that is, it increases the width occupied by label+labelsep+item-content.
\item*: It is the second optional argument and works like a numbered item, but adding a symbol to the left of the label. When * is present two optional arguments may be used \item*[sym][sep] and may also be used in conjunction with \item(join)*[sym][sep].
\item(join)[opt]: Works like \item[opt] (not numbered), but joining columns.

All contents of label, labelsep, item-content are captured in a \hbox+\minipage, processed and then printed horizontally leaving the column-sep space between them.
When comparing the output of the enumerate environment with my environment mylist* delivered by ngpdf.com the differences are observed:

The first structure is correct and the second one should look the same when using columns=1, but it doesn't.  In the documentation for tagpdf-code and latex-lab-block I can see a couple of functions that I think are the ones I need to put here:
\tag_stop:
\tag_start:
\tagpdfparaOn
\tagpdfparaOff
\tag_struct_end:
\tag_mc_end:
\tag_struct_begin:n {tag=LI}
\tag_struct_begin:n {tag=Lbl}
\tag_struct_begin:n {tag=LBody}
\tag_mc_begin:n {tag=Lbl}

So my question is:
How can modify my redefinition of \item to be compatible with tagging?
That is, where to put the commands shown above to stop automatic tagging and get a correct list structure.
The non-MWE is the following:
\DocumentMetadata{ lang=en-US, pdfversion=2.0, testphase={phase-III,math,table,title,firstaid}, uncompress }% pdfstandard=ua-2,
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Copy list with tagging support (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725389)
\hook_gput_code:nnn {begindocument} { mylist }
  {
    \cs_new_eq:NN   \__mylist_start_list:nn \list
    \cs_new_eq:NN   \__mylist_stop_list: \endlist
    \NewCommandCopy \__mylist_item_std:w \item
  }
% Some vars
\int_new:N \l_mylist_level_int
\tl_new:N  \g_mylist_counter_styles_tl
\box_new:N \l_mylist_label_width_by_box
\dim_new:N \l_mylist_current_widest_dim
\dim_new:N \itemwidth % public
\bool_new:N \l_mylist_hyperref_bool
% Hyperref support
\IfPackageLoadedTF { hyperref }
  {
    \bool_set_true:N \l_mylist_hyperref_bool
  }{}
% Counter
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_counters:n #1
  {
    \tl_new:c  { l_mylist_counter_#1_tl }
    \tl_set:cn { l_mylist_counter_#1_tl } { mycounx#1 }
    \newcounter{ mycounx#1 }
  }
\__mylist_counters:n {vii}
% Width label
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_label_width_by_box:Nn #1#2
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_mylist_label_width_by_box {#2}
    \dim_set:Nn #1 { \box_wd:N \l_mylist_label_width_by_box }
  }
% Register counters and set default labelwidth
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn #1 #2
  {
    \tl_const:cn { c_mylist_widest_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _tl } {#2}
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_mylist_counter_styles_tl {#1}
  }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \arabic { 0 }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \Alph { M }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \alph { m }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \Roman { VIII }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \roman { viii }
% Style for label
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_label_style:Nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_clear_new:N #1
    \tl_put_right:Ne #1 { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#3} }
    \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_mylist_widest_label_tl #1
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \g_mylist_counter_styles_tl
      {
        \tl_replace_all:Nne #1 { ##1* } { \exp_not:N ##1 {#2} }
        \tl_greplace_all:Nne \g_mylist_widest_label_tl { ##1* }
           { \tl_use:c { c_mylist_widest_ \cs_to_str:N ##1 _tl } }
      }
     \__mylist_label_width_by_box:Nn \l_mylist_current_widest_dim
       { \tl_use:N \g_mylist_widest_label_tl }
     \tl_set_eq:cN { the #2 } #1
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mylist_label_style:Nnn { cvn }
% Keys and vars for levels
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_keys_and_vars:nnnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6
  {
    \bool_new:c { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_bool }
    \bool_new:c { l_mylist_wrap_label_opt_#1_bool }
    \bool_new:c { l_mylist_wrap_label_#1_bool     }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_dim  }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_leftmargin_#1_dim      }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_itemindent_#1_dim      }
    \tl_new:c   { l_mylist_fake_item_indent_#1_tl }
    \tl_new:c   { l_mylist_label_#1_tl            }
    \str_new:c  { l_mylist_align_label_#1_str     }
    \bool_new:c { l_mylist_item_starred_#1_bool   }
    \int_new:c  { l_mylist_item_column_pos_#1_int }
    \int_new:c  { l_mylist_item_label_#1_int      }
    \int_new:c  { g_mylist_item_count_all_#1_int  }
    \int_new:c  { l_mylist_joined_item_#1_int     }
    \int_new:c  { l_mylist_joined_item_aux_#1_int }
    \int_new:c  { l_mylist_tmpa_#1_int            }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_tmpa_#1_dim            }
    \box_new:c  { l_mylist_item_text_#1_box       }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_joined_width_#1_dim    }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_item_width_#1_dim      }
    \tl_new:c   { g_mylist_item_symbol_aux_#1_tl  }
    \keys_define:nn { mylist / level-#1 }
      {
        font           .tl_set:c   = { l_mylist_label_font_style_#1_tl },
        itemindent     .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_fake_item_indent_#1_dim },
        labelsep       .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_labelsep_#1_dim },
        labelsep       .initial:n  = {0.3333em},
        labelwidth     .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_labelwidth_#1_dim },
        label          .code:n     = {
                                       \__mylist_label_style:cvn { l_mylist_label_#1_tl }
                                         { l_mylist_counter_#1_tl } {##1}
                                       \dim_set_eq:cN
                                         { l_mylist_labelwidth_#1_dim } \l_mylist_current_widest_dim
                                     },
        label          .initial:n  = {#2},
        wrap-label     .cs_set_protected:cp = { __mylist_wrapper_label_#1:n } ##1,
        wrap-label     .initial:n  = {##1},
        wrap-label*    .code:n     = {
                                      \bool_set_true:c { l_mylist_wrap_label_opt_#1_bool }
                                      \keys_set:nn { mylist / level-#1 } { wrap-label = {##1} }
                                     },
        item-sym*      .tl_set:c   = { l_mylist_item_symbol_#1_tl },
        item-sym*      .initial:n  = {\textasteriskcentered},
        item-pos*      .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_item_symbol_sep_#1_dim },
        align .choice:,
        align / left   .code:n     = \str_set:cn { l_mylist_align_label_#1_str } { l },
        align / right  .code:n     = \str_set:cn { l_mylist_align_label_#1_str } { r },
        align / center .code:n     = \str_set:cn { l_mylist_align_label_#1_str } { c },
        align .initial:n = left,
        list-offset    .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_listoffset_#1_dim },
        list-indent    .meta:n     = { list-offset = ##1 },
        columns-sep    .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_columns_sep_#1_dim },
        columns        .int_set:c  = { l_mylist_columns_#1_int },
        columns        .initial:n  = 2,
        topsep         .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_topsep_#1_skip },
        topsep         .initial:n  = {#3},
        partopsep      .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_partopsep_#1_skip },
        partopsep      .initial:n  = {#4},
        parsep         .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_parsep_#1_skip },
        parsep         .initial:n  = {#5},
        itemsep        .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_itemsep_#1_skip },
        itemsep        .initial:n  = {#6},
        rightmargin    .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_rightmargin_#1_dim },
        listparindent  .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_listparindent_#1_dim },
      }
  }
% Set keys and vars
\__mylist_keys_and_vars:nnnnnn { vii } { \arabic*.} { 8.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 4.0pt }
  { 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt } { 4.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt } { 4.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt }
% Internal function for fake |\itemindent|
\cs_set_protected:Nn \__mylist_fake_item_vii:
  {
    \dim_compare:nNnT
      { \l_mylist_fake_item_indent_vii_dim } > { \c_zero_dim }
      {
        \tl_set:Ne \l_mylist_fake_item_indent_vii_tl
          {
            \exp_not:N \mode_leave_vertical:
            \exp_not:N \skip_horizontal:N \l_mylist_fake_item_indent_vii_dim
          }
      }
   }
% Calc \itemindent and \leftmargin
% #1: \l_mylist_labelwidth_i_dim      #2: \l_mylist_labelsep_i_dim     #3: \l_mylist_listoffset_i_dim
% #4: \l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_i_dim  #5: \l_mylist_leftmargin_i_dim   #6: \l_mylist_itemindent_i_dim
% #7: \l_mylist_custom_margin_i_bool
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_calc_hspace:NNNNNNN #1#2#3#4#5#6#7
  {
    \bool_if:nF #7 { \dim_set:Nn #4 { #1 + #2} }
    \dim_compare:nNnTF {#4} < { 0pt }
       {
         \dim_set:Nn #6 { #1 + #2 - #4}
         \dim_set:Nn #5 { #1 + #2 + #3 - #6 }
       }
       {
         \dim_compare:nNnT {#4} = {#1+#2}
           { \dim_set:Nn #6 { 0pt} }
         \dim_compare:nNnT {#4} < {#1+#2}
           { \dim_set:Nn #6 { #1 + #2 - #4} }
         \dim_compare:nNnT {#4} > {#1+#2}
           { \dim_set:Nn #6 { -#1 - #2 + #4}  \dim_set:Nn #6 { #6*-1} }
         \dim_set:Nn #5 { #1 + #2 + #3 - #6 }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mylist_calc_hspace:NNNNNNN { ccccccc }
% Second argument of list
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mylist_make_second_arg:n #1
  {
    \cs_new_protected:cpn { __mylist_list_arg_two_#1: }
      {
        \bool_set_true:c { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_bool }
        \dim_zero:c { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_dim }
        \__mylist_calc_hspace:ccccccc
          { l_mylist_labelwidth_#1_dim } { l_mylist_labelsep_#1_dim }
          { l_mylist_listoffset_#1_dim } { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_dim }
          { l_mylist_leftmargin_#1_dim } { l_mylist_itemindent_#1_dim }
          { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_bool }
        \clist_map_inline:nn
          { labelsep, labelwidth, itemindent, leftmargin, rightmargin, listparindent }
          { \dim_set_eq:cc {####1} { l_mylist_####1_#1_dim } }
        \clist_map_inline:nn { topsep, parsep, partopsep, itemsep }
          { \skip_set_eq:cc {####1} { l_mylist_####1_#1_skip } }
        \skip_set_eq:Nc \parsep  { l_mylist_itemsep_#1_skip }
        \skip_zero:N \partopsep
        \usecounter { mycounx#1 }
        \__mylist_fake_item_vii:
      }
  }
\__mylist_make_second_arg:n {vii}
% Define default item-width (columns width).
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mylist_starred_columns_set_vii:
  {
    \dim_compare:nNnT { \l_mylist_columns_sep_vii_dim } = { \c_zero_dim }
      {
        \dim_set:Nn \l_mylist_columns_sep_vii_dim
          {
            ( \l_mylist_labelwidth_vii_dim + \l_mylist_labelsep_vii_dim )
            / \l_mylist_columns_vii_int
          }
      }
    \int_set:Nn \l_mylist_tmpa_vii_int { \l_mylist_columns_vii_int - 1 }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_mylist_item_width_vii_dim
      {
        ( \linewidth - \l_mylist_columns_sep_vii_dim * \l_mylist_tmpa_vii_int )
        / \l_mylist_columns_vii_int
        - \l_mylist_labelwidth_vii_dim
        - \l_mylist_labelsep_vii_dim
      }
    \dim_compare:nNnT { \l_mylist_rightmargin_vii_dim } > { \c_zero_dim }
      {
        \dim_sub:Nn \l_mylist_item_width_vii_dim
          {
            ( \l_mylist_rightmargin_vii_dim * \l_mylist_tmpa_vii_int )
            / \l_mylist_columns_vii_int
          }
        \dim_add:Nn \l_mylist_columns_sep_vii_dim
          {
            \l_mylist_rightmargin_vii_dim
          }
      }
  }
% Set width for joined item's
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_starred_joined_item_vii:n #1
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int {#1}
    \int_compare:nNnT { \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int } > { \l_mylist_columns_vii_int }
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int
          {
            \l_mylist_columns_vii_int - \l_mylist_item_column_pos_vii_int + 1
          }
      }
    \int_compare:nNnT
      { \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int }
        >
      { \l_mylist_columns_vii_int - \l_mylist_item_column_pos_vii_int + 1 }
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int
          {
            \l_mylist_columns_vii_int - \l_mylist_item_column_pos_vii_int + 1
          }
      }
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int } > { 1 }
      {
        \int_set_eq:NN \l_mylist_joined_item_aux_vii_int \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int
        \int_decr:N \l_mylist_joined_item_aux_vii_int
        \int_add:Nn \l_mylist_item_column_pos_vii_int { \l_mylist_joined_item_aux_vii_int }
        \int_gadd:Nn \g_mylist_item_count_all_vii_int { \l_mylist_joined_item_aux_vii_int }
        \dim_set:Nn \l_mylist_joined_width_vii_dim
          {
            \l_mylist_item_width_vii_dim * \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int
            + (  \l_mylist_labelwidth_vii_dim + \l_mylist_labelsep_vii_dim
               + \l_mylist_columns_sep_vii_dim
              )*\l_mylist_joined_item_aux_vii_int
          }
        \dim_set_eq:NN \itemwidth \l_mylist_joined_width_vii_dim
      }
      {
        \dim_set_eq:NN \l_mylist_joined_width_vii_dim \l_mylist_item_width_vii_dim
        \dim_set_eq:NN \itemwidth \l_mylist_item_width_vii_dim
      }
  }
% key =val
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_parse_keys_vii:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_novalue:nF {#1}
      {
        \keys_set:nn { mylist / level-vii } {#1}
      }
  }
% Environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mylist*}{ O{} }
  {
    \int_incr:N \l_mylist_level_int
    \__mylist_parse_keys_vii:n {#1}
    \__mylist_start_list:nn {  }
      {
        \__mylist_list_arg_two_vii:
      }
    \__mylist_starred_columns_set_vii:
    \item[] \scan_stop:
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__mylist_stop_item_tmp_vii: \__mylist_first_item_tmp:
    \cs_set_eq:NN \item \__mylist_start_item_tmp_vii:
    \ignorespaces
  }
  {
    \__mylist_stop_item_tmp_vii:
    \__mylist_remove_extra_parsep_vii:
    \__mylist_stop_list:
  }
% Remove unwanted space at start first item
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \__mylist_first_item_tmp:
  {
    \skip_horizontal:n { - \l_mylist_labelwidth_vii_dim - \l_mylist_labelsep_vii_dim }
  }
% Now implement boxed \item's
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \__mylist_start_item_tmp_vii:
  {
    \__mylist_stop_item_tmp_vii:
    \int_incr:N \l_mylist_item_label_vii_int % Need for tag maybe?
    \int_incr:N \l_mylist_item_column_pos_vii_int
    \int_gincr:N \g_mylist_item_count_all_vii_int
    \__mylist_item_peek_args_vii:
  }
% Peek argument for \item(join)*[sym][sep]
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mylist_item_peek_args_vii:
  {
    \peek_meaning:NTF (
      { \__mylist_joined_item_vii:w }
      { \__mylist_joined_item_vii:w (1) }
  }
% Joined item's \item(join)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_joined_item_vii:w (#1)
  {
    \__mylist_starred_joined_item_vii:n {#1}
    \peek_meaning_remove:NTF *
      { \__mylist_starred_item_vii:w }
      { \__mylist_standar_item_vii:w }
  }
% Set \item[opt]
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_standar_item_vii:w
  {
    \bool_set_false:N \l_mylist_item_starred_vii_bool
    \peek_meaning:NTF [
      {
        \bool_set_eq:NN \l_mylist_wrap_label_vii_bool \l_mylist_wrap_label_opt_vii_bool
        \__mylist_start_item_vii:w
      }
      {
        \bool_set_true:N \l_mylist_wrap_label_vii_bool
        \legacy_if_set_true:n { @noitemarg }
        \__mylist_start_item_vii:w [ \l_mylist_label_vii_tl ]
      }
  }
% Set \item*[sym][sep]
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_starred_item_vii:w
  {
    \bool_set_true:N \l_mylist_item_starred_vii_bool
    \bool_set_true:N \l_mylist_wrap_label_vii_bool
    \peek_meaning:NTF [
      { \__mylist_starred_item_vii_aux_i:w }
      { \__mylist_starred_item_vii_aux_ii:w }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_starred_item_vii_aux_i:w [#1]
  {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_mylist_item_symbol_aux_vii_tl {#1}
    \__mylist_starred_item_vii_aux_ii:w
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_starred_item_vii_aux_ii:w
  {
    \peek_meaning:NTF [
      { \__mylist_starred_item_vii_aux_iii:w }
      {
        \dim_set_eq:NN \l_mylist_item_symbol_sep_vii_dim \l_mylist_labelsep_vii_dim
        \legacy_if_set_true:n { @noitemarg }
        \__mylist_start_item_vii:w [ \l_mylist_label_vii_tl ]
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_starred_item_vii_aux_iii:w [#1]
  {
    \dim_set:Nn \l_mylist_item_symbol_sep_vii_dim {#1}
    \legacy_if_set_true:n { @noitemarg }
    \__mylist_start_item_vii:w [ \l_mylist_label_vii_tl ]
  }
% Print numbered \item [ \legacy_if_set_true:n { @hyper@item } (hyperref-doc p170) ]
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mylist_print_number_item_vii:
  {
    \legacy_if:nT { @noitemarg }
      {
        \legacy_if_set_false:n { @noitemarg }
        \legacy_if:nT { @nmbrlist }
          {
            \bool_if:NT \l_mylist_hyperref_bool
              {
                \legacy_if_set_true:n { @hyper@item }
              }
            \refstepcounter{mycounxvii}
          }
      }
  }
% Fake \makelabel using \makebox
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_fake_make_label_vii:n #1
  {
     \bool_if:NT \l_mylist_item_starred_vii_bool
        {
          \tl_if_blank:VT \g_mylist_item_symbol_aux_vii_tl
            {
              \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_mylist_item_symbol_aux_vii_tl \l_mylist_item_symbol_vii_tl
            }
          \mode_leave_vertical:
          \skip_horizontal:n { -\l_mylist_item_symbol_sep_vii_dim }
          \hbox_overlap_left:n { \g_mylist_item_symbol_aux_vii_tl }
          \skip_horizontal:N \l_mylist_item_symbol_sep_vii_dim
          \tl_gclear:N \g_mylist_item_symbol_aux_vii_tl
        }
      \bool_if:NTF \l_mylist_wrap_label_vii_bool
        {
          \makebox[ \l_mylist_labelwidth_vii_dim ][ \l_mylist_align_label_vii_str ]
            {
              \tl_use:N \l_mylist_label_font_style_vii_tl
              \__mylist_wrapper_label_vii:n {#1}
            }
        }
        {
          \makebox[ \l_mylist_labelwidth_vii_dim ][ \l_mylist_align_label_vii_str ]
            {
              \tl_use:N \l_mylist_label_font_style_vii_tl  #1
            }
        }
      \skip_horizontal:N \l_mylist_labelsep_vii_dim
  }
% Real \item definition
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__mylist_start_item_vii:w [#1]
  {
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__mylist_stop_item_tmp_vii: \__mylist_stop_item_vii:
    \__mylist_print_number_item_vii:
    \box_clear:N \l_mylist_item_text_vii_box
    \hbox_set_to_wd:Nnw \l_mylist_item_text_vii_box
      {
        \l_mylist_joined_width_vii_dim
        + \l_mylist_labelwidth_vii_dim
        + \l_mylist_labelsep_vii_dim
      }
      \__mylist_fake_make_label_vii:n {#1}
      \begin{minipage}[t]{ \l_mylist_joined_width_vii_dim }
        \dim_set_eq:NN  \parindent \l_mylist_listparindent_vii_dim
        \skip_set_eq:NN \parskip \l_mylist_parsep_vii_skip
        \tl_use:N \l_mylist_fake_item_indent_vii_tl
   }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \__mylist_stop_item_vii:
  {
      \end{minipage}
    \hbox_set_end:
    \int_set:Nn \hbadness { 10000 }
    \box_use_drop:N \l_mylist_item_text_vii_box
    \int_compare:nNnTF
      { \l_mylist_item_column_pos_vii_int } = { \l_mylist_columns_vii_int }
      {
        \par\noindent
        \int_zero:N \l_mylist_item_column_pos_vii_int
      }
      {
        \skip_horizontal:N \l_mylist_columns_sep_vii_dim
      }
  }
% Remove extra \parsep (\itemsep)
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mylist_remove_extra_parsep_vii:
  {
    \int_compare:nNnT
      {
        \int_mod:nn
          { \g_mylist_item_count_all_vii_int } { \l_mylist_columns_vii_int }
      }
      =
      { 0 }
      {
        \para_end:
        \skip_vertical:n { -\l_mylist_itemsep_vii_skip }
        \skip_vertical:N \c_zero_skip
        \int_gzero:N \g_mylist_item_count_all_vii_int
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Using \texttt{enumerate} first \verb|\item| here.
  \item Using \texttt{enumerate} second \verb|\item| here.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{mylist*}[columns=1]
  \item Using \texttt{mylist*} first \verb|\item| here.
  \item Using \texttt{mylist*} first \verb|\item| here.
\end{mylist*}

\end{document}


hm. Well at first I don't like your optional arguments. Imho you should handle everything with key-val. So \item[join=2,suffix=*,text=blub]. At second, neither lists nor tagging are simple, and to get it working properly we have completly reimplemented the list code and based it on templates. As you are copying the default commands you are actually mixing the new methods with the legacy list implementation and imho this gives chaos. As an example I naturally took care to properly integrate hyperref so  testing for @hyper@item should not be needed.

I'm not sure if the new code already allows to implement your use case, but imho it would be better if you tried to implement it with the templates and asks us to extend the code if you see that something is missing.

@UlrikeFischer Thank you very much for your comments, I have been able to achieve it, the key was to stop tagging when using \item (which caused problems), the real capture that I want is in the function \__mylist_start_item_vii:w and that is where I must apply tagging to generate the list.

@UlrikeFischer Could you achieve the horizontal effect? ​​I have put a temporary answer, and according to the tests the list code is correct, I just need to make it horizontal...can you put an answer adding that?

This is the final code that solves my question, the comparison MWE was not correct and thanks to Ulrike Fischer's comments I have been able to make the code work.
The key was to inject the code for tagging in the right places and disable it in others. The documentation for lttagging, tagpdf-code and ltsockets-code together with (https://github.com/latex3/tagpdf/blob/main/experiments/test-list-attribute.tex) allowed me to find the solution.
\DocumentMetadata{ lang=en-US, pdfversion=2.0, testphase={phase-III,math,table,title,firstaid}, uncompress }% pdfstandard=ua-2,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagpdf-debug}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Copy list with tagging support (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725389)
\hook_gput_code:nnn {begindocument} { mylist }
  {
    \cs_new_eq:NN   \__mylist_start_list:nn \list
    \cs_new_eq:NN   \__mylist_stop_list: \endlist
    \NewCommandCopy \__mylist_item_std:w \item
  }
% Some vars
\int_new:N \l_mylist_level_int
\tl_new:N  \g_mylist_counter_styles_tl
\box_new:N \l_mylist_label_width_by_box
\dim_new:N \l_mylist_current_widest_dim
\dim_new:N \itemwidth % public
% Counter
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_counters:n #1
  {
    \tl_new:c  { l_mylist_counter_#1_tl }
    \tl_set:cn { l_mylist_counter_#1_tl } { mycounx#1 }
    \newcounter{ mycounx#1 }
  }
\__mylist_counters:n {vii}
% Width label
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_label_width_by_box:Nn #1#2
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_mylist_label_width_by_box {#2}
    \dim_set:Nn #1 { \box_wd:N \l_mylist_label_width_by_box }
  }
% Register counters and set default labelwidth
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn #1 #2
  {
    \tl_const:cn { c_mylist_widest_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _tl } {#2}
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_mylist_counter_styles_tl {#1}
  }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \arabic { 0 }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \Alph { M }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \alph { m }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \Roman { VIII }
\__mylist_register_counter_style:Nn \roman { viii }
% Style for label
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_label_style:Nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_clear_new:N #1
    \tl_put_right:Ne #1 { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#3} }
    \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_mylist_widest_label_tl #1
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \g_mylist_counter_styles_tl
      {
        \tl_replace_all:Nne #1 { ##1* } { \exp_not:N ##1 {#2} }
        \tl_greplace_all:Nne \g_mylist_widest_label_tl { ##1* }
           { \tl_use:c { c_mylist_widest_ \cs_to_str:N ##1 _tl } }
      }
     \__mylist_label_width_by_box:Nn \l_mylist_current_widest_dim
       { \tl_use:N \g_mylist_widest_label_tl }
     \tl_set_eq:cN { the #2 } #1
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mylist_label_style:Nnn { cvn }
% Keys and vars for levels
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_keys_and_vars:nnnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6
  {
    \bool_new:c { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_bool }
    \bool_new:c { l_mylist_wrap_label_opt_#1_bool }
    \bool_new:c { l_mylist_wrap_label_#1_bool     }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_dim  }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_leftmargin_#1_dim      }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_itemindent_#1_dim      }
    \tl_new:c   { l_mylist_fake_item_indent_#1_tl }
    \tl_new:c   { l_mylist_label_#1_tl            }
    \str_new:c  { l_mylist_align_label_#1_str     }
    \bool_new:c { l_mylist_item_starred_#1_bool   }
    \int_new:c  { l_mylist_item_column_pos_#1_int }
    \int_new:c  { g_mylist_item_count_all_#1_int  }
    \int_new:c  { l_mylist_joined_item_#1_int     }
    \int_new:c  { l_mylist_joined_item_aux_#1_int }
    \int_new:c  { l_mylist_tmpa_#1_int            }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_tmpa_#1_dim            }
    \box_new:c  { l_mylist_item_text_#1_box       }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_joined_width_#1_dim    }
    \dim_new:c  { l_mylist_item_width_#1_dim      }
    \tl_new:c   { g_mylist_item_symbol_aux_#1_tl  }
    \keys_define:nn { mylist / level-#1 }
      {
        font           .tl_set:c   = { l_mylist_label_font_style_#1_tl },
        itemindent     .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_fake_item_indent_#1_dim },
        labelsep       .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_labelsep_#1_dim },
        labelsep       .initial:n  = {0.3333em},
        labelwidth     .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_labelwidth_#1_dim },
        label          .code:n     = {
                                       \__mylist_label_style:cvn { l_mylist_label_#1_tl }
                                         { l_mylist_counter_#1_tl } {##1}
                                       \dim_set_eq:cN
                                         { l_mylist_labelwidth_#1_dim } \l_mylist_current_widest_dim
                                     },
        label          .initial:n  = {#2},
        wrap-label     .cs_set_protected:cp = { __mylist_wrapper_label_#1:n } ##1,
        wrap-label     .initial:n  = {##1},
        wrap-label*    .code:n     = {
                                      \bool_set_true:c { l_mylist_wrap_label_opt_#1_bool }
                                      \keys_set:nn { mylist / level-#1 } { wrap-label = {##1} }
                                     },
        item-sym*      .tl_set:c   = { l_mylist_item_symbol_#1_tl },
        item-sym*      .initial:n  = {\textasteriskcentered},
        item-pos*      .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_item_symbol_sep_#1_dim },
        align .choice:,
        align / left   .code:n     = \str_set:cn { l_mylist_align_label_#1_str } { l },
        align / right  .code:n     = \str_set:cn { l_mylist_align_label_#1_str } { r },
        align / center .code:n     = \str_set:cn { l_mylist_align_label_#1_str } { c },
        align .initial:n = left,
        list-offset    .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_listoffset_#1_dim },
        list-indent    .meta:n     = { list-offset = ##1 },
        columns-sep    .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_columns_sep_#1_dim },
        columns        .int_set:c  = { l_mylist_columns_#1_int },
        columns        .initial:n  = 2,
        topsep         .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_topsep_#1_skip },
        topsep         .initial:n  = {#3},
        partopsep      .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_partopsep_#1_skip },
        partopsep      .initial:n  = {#4},
        parsep         .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_parsep_#1_skip },
        parsep         .initial:n  = {#5},
        itemsep        .skip_set:c = { l_mylist_itemsep_#1_skip },
        itemsep        .initial:n  = {#6},
        rightmargin    .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_rightmargin_#1_dim },
        listparindent  .dim_set:c  = { l_mylist_listparindent_#1_dim },
      }
  }
% Set keys and vars
\__mylist_keys_and_vars:nnnnnn { vii } { \arabic*.} { 8.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 4.0pt }
  { 2.0pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt } { 4.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt } { 4.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt }
% Internal function for fake |\itemindent|
\cs_set_protected:Nn \__mylist_fake_item_vii:
  {
    \dim_compare:nNnT
      { \l_mylist_fake_item_indent_vii_dim } > { \c_zero_dim }
      {
        \tl_set:Ne \l_mylist_fake_item_indent_vii_tl
          {
            \exp_not:N \mode_leave_vertical:
            \exp_not:N \skip_horizontal:N \l_mylist_fake_item_indent_vii_dim
          }
      }
   }
% Calc \itemindent and \leftmargin
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_calc_hspace:NNNNNNN #1#2#3#4#5#6#7
  {
    \bool_if:nF #7 { \dim_set:Nn #4 { #1 + #2} }
    \dim_compare:nNnTF {#4} < { 0pt }
       {
         \dim_set:Nn #6 { #1 + #2 - #4}
         \dim_set:Nn #5 { #1 + #2 + #3 - #6 }
       }
       {
         \dim_compare:nNnT {#4} = {#1+#2}
           { \dim_set:Nn #6 { 0pt} }
         \dim_compare:nNnT {#4} < {#1+#2}
           { \dim_set:Nn #6 { #1 + #2 - #4} }
         \dim_compare:nNnT {#4} > {#1+#2}
           { \dim_set:Nn #6 { -#1 - #2 + #4}  \dim_set:Nn #6 { #6*-1} }
         \dim_set:Nn #5 { #1 + #2 + #3 - #6 }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mylist_calc_hspace:NNNNNNN { ccccccc }
% Second argument of list
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mylist_make_second_arg:n #1
  {
    \cs_new_protected:cpn { __mylist_list_arg_two_#1: }
      {
        \bool_set_true:c { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_bool }
        \dim_zero:c { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_dim }
        \__mylist_calc_hspace:ccccccc
          { l_mylist_labelwidth_#1_dim } { l_mylist_labelsep_#1_dim }
          { l_mylist_listoffset_#1_dim } { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_dim }
          { l_mylist_leftmargin_#1_dim } { l_mylist_itemindent_#1_dim }
          { l_mylist_leftmargin_tmp_#1_bool }
        \clist_map_inline:nn
          { labelsep, labelwidth, itemindent, leftmargin, rightmargin, listparindent }
          { \dim_set_eq:cc {####1} { l_mylist_####1_#1_dim } }
        \clist_map_inline:nn { topsep, parsep, partopsep, itemsep }
          { \skip_set_eq:cc {####1} { l_mylist_####1_#1_skip } }
        \skip_set_eq:Nc \parsep  { l_mylist_itemsep_#1_skip }
        \skip_zero:N \partopsep
        \usecounter { mycounx#1 }
        \__mylist_fake_item_vii:
      }
  }
\__mylist_make_second_arg:n {vii}
% Define default item-width (columns width).
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mylist_starred_columns_set_vii:
  {
    \dim_compare:nNnT { \l_mylist_columns_sep_vii_dim } = { \c_zero_dim }
      {
        \dim_set:Nn \l_mylist_columns_sep_vii_dim
          {
            ( \l_mylist_labelwidth_vii_dim + \l_mylist_labelsep_vii_dim )
            / \l_mylist_columns_vii_int
          }
      }
    \int_set:Nn \l_mylist_tmpa_vii_int { \l_mylist_columns_vii_int - 1 }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_mylist_item_width_vii_dim
      {
        ( \linewidth - \l_mylist_columns_sep_vii_dim * \l_mylist_tmpa_vii_int )
        / \l_mylist_columns_vii_int
        - \l_mylist_labelwidth_vii_dim
        - \l_mylist_labelsep_vii_dim
      }
    \dim_compare:nNnT { \l_mylist_rightmargin_vii_dim } > { \c_zero_dim }
      {
        \dim_sub:Nn \l_mylist_item_width_vii_dim
          {
            ( \l_mylist_rightmargin_vii_dim * \l_mylist_tmpa_vii_int )
            / \l_mylist_columns_vii_int
          }
        \dim_add:Nn \l_mylist_columns_sep_vii_dim
          {
            \l_mylist_rightmargin_vii_dim
          }
      }
  }
% Set width for joined item's
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_starred_joined_item_vii:n #1
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int {#1}
    \int_compare:nNnT { \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int } > { \l_mylist_columns_vii_int }
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int
          {
            \l_mylist_columns_vii_int - \l_mylist_item_column_pos_vii_int + 1
          }
      }
    \int_compare:nNnT
      { \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int }
        >
      { \l_mylist_columns_vii_int - \l_mylist_item_column_pos_vii_int + 1 }
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int
          {
            \l_mylist_columns_vii_int - \l_mylist_item_column_pos_vii_int + 1
          }
      }
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int } > { 1 }
      {
        \int_set_eq:NN \l_mylist_joined_item_aux_vii_int \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int
        \int_decr:N \l_mylist_joined_item_aux_vii_int
        \int_add:Nn \l_mylist_item_column_pos_vii_int { \l_mylist_joined_item_aux_vii_int }
        \int_gadd:Nn \g_mylist_item_count_all_vii_int { \l_mylist_joined_item_aux_vii_int }
        \dim_set:Nn \l_mylist_joined_width_vii_dim
          {
            \l_mylist_item_width_vii_dim * \l_mylist_joined_item_vii_int
            + (  \l_mylist_labelwidth_vii_dim + \l_mylist_labelsep_vii_dim
               + \l_mylist_columns_sep_vii_dim
              )*\l_mylist_joined_item_aux_vii_int
          }
        \dim_set_eq:NN \itemwidth \l_mylist_joined_width_vii_dim
      }
      {
        \dim_set_eq:NN \l_mylist_joined_width_vii_dim \l_mylist_item_width_vii_dim
        \dim_set_eq:NN \itemwidth \l_mylist_item_width_vii_dim
      }
  }
% key =val
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_parse_keys_vii:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_novalue:nF {#1}
      {
        \keys_set:nn { mylist / level-vii } {#1}
      }
  }
% Environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mylist*}{ O{} }
  {
    \int_incr:N \l_mylist_level_int
    \__mylist_parse_keys_vii:n {#1}
    \__mylist_start_list:nn {  }
      {
        \__mylist_list_arg_two_vii:
      }
    \__mylist_starred_columns_set_vii:
    \SuspendTagging{mylist*} % Stop tagging
    \item[] \scan_stop:
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__mylist_stop_item_tmp_vii: \__mylist_first_item_tmp:
    \cs_set_eq:NN \item \__mylist_start_item_tmp_vii:
    \ignorespaces
  }
  {
    \IfDocumentMetadataTF { \tag_struct_end: } { } % Close {tag=text-unit}
    \__mylist_stop_item_tmp_vii:
    \__mylist_remove_extra_parsep_vii:
    \__mylist_stop_list:
  }
% Remove unwanted space at start first item
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \__mylist_first_item_tmp:
  {
    \skip_horizontal:n { - \l_mylist_labelwidth_vii_dim - \l_mylist_labelsep_vii_dim }
  }
% Now implement boxed \item's
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \__mylist_start_item_tmp_vii:
  {

    \__mylist_stop_item_tmp_vii:
    \int_incr:N \l_mylist_item_column_pos_vii_int
    \int_gincr:N \g_mylist_item_count_all_vii_int
    \__mylist_item_peek_args_vii:
  }
% Peek argument for \item(join)*[sym][sep]
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mylist_item_peek_args_vii:
  {
    \peek_meaning:NTF (
      { \__mylist_joined_item_vii:w }
      { \__mylist_joined_item_vii:w (1) }
  }
% Joined item's \item(join)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_joined_item_vii:w (#1)
  {
    \__mylist_starred_joined_item_vii:n {#1}
    \peek_meaning_remove:NTF *
      { \__mylist_starred_item_vii:w }
      { \__mylist_standar_item_vii:w }
  }
% Set \item[opt]
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_standar_item_vii:w
  {
    \bool_set_false:N \l_mylist_item_starred_vii_bool
    \peek_meaning:NTF [
      {
        \bool_set_eq:NN \l_mylist_wrap_label_vii_bool \l_mylist_wrap_label_opt_vii_bool
        \__mylist_start_item_vii:w
      }
      {
        \bool_set_true:N \l_mylist_wrap_label_vii_bool
        \legacy_if_set_true:n { @noitemarg }
        \__mylist_start_item_vii:w [ \l_mylist_label_vii_tl ]
      }
  }
% Set \item*[sym][sep]
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_starred_item_vii:w
  {
    \bool_set_true:N \l_mylist_item_starred_vii_bool
    \bool_set_true:N \l_mylist_wrap_label_vii_bool
    \peek_meaning:NTF [
      { \__mylist_starred_item_vii_aux_i:w }
      { \__mylist_starred_item_vii_aux_ii:w }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_starred_item_vii_aux_i:w [#1]
  {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_mylist_item_symbol_aux_vii_tl {#1}
    \__mylist_starred_item_vii_aux_ii:w
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_starred_item_vii_aux_ii:w
  {
    \peek_meaning:NTF [
      { \__mylist_starred_item_vii_aux_iii:w }
      {
        \dim_set_eq:NN \l_mylist_item_symbol_sep_vii_dim \l_mylist_labelsep_vii_dim
        \legacy_if_set_true:n { @noitemarg }
        \__mylist_start_item_vii:w [ \l_mylist_label_vii_tl ]
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_starred_item_vii_aux_iii:w [#1]
  {
    \dim_set:Nn \l_mylist_item_symbol_sep_vii_dim {#1}
    \legacy_if_set_true:n { @noitemarg }
    \__mylist_start_item_vii:w [ \l_mylist_label_vii_tl ]
  }
% Print numbered \item
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mylist_print_number_item_vii:
  {
    \legacy_if:nT { @noitemarg }
      {
        \legacy_if_set_false:n { @noitemarg }
        \legacy_if:nT { @nmbrlist }
          {
            \refstepcounter{mycounxvii}
          }
      }
  }
% Fake \makelabel using \makebox
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mylist_fake_make_label_vii:n #1
  {
    \__mylist_print_number_item_vii:
    \bool_if:NT \l_mylist_item_starred_vii_bool
      {
        \tl_if_blank:VT \g_mylist_item_symbol_aux_vii_tl
          {
            \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_mylist_item_symbol_aux_vii_tl \l_mylist_item_symbol_vii_tl
          }
        \mode_leave_vertical:
        \skip_horizontal:n { -\l_mylist_item_symbol_sep_vii_dim }
        \hbox_overlap_left:n { \g_mylist_item_symbol_aux_vii_tl }
        \skip_horizontal:N \l_mylist_item_symbol_sep_vii_dim
        \tl_gclear:N \g_mylist_item_symbol_aux_vii_tl
      }
    \makebox[ \l_mylist_labelwidth_vii_dim ][ \l_mylist_align_label_vii_str ]
      {
        \tl_use:N \l_mylist_label_font_style_vii_tl
        \bool_if:NTF \l_mylist_wrap_label_vii_bool
          {
            \__mylist_wrapper_label_vii:n {#1}
          }
          { #1 }
      }
    \skip_horizontal:N \l_mylist_labelsep_vii_dim
  }
% Tagging (ltsockets-code.pdf)
\socket_new:nn {tagsupport/mylist/taglist}{ 1 }
\socket_new_plug:nnn {tagsupport/mylist/taglist} {start-list-tags}
  {
    \ResumeTagging{#1}
    \tag_struct_begin:n {tag=LI}
    \tag_struct_begin:n {tag=Lbl}
    \tag_mc_begin:n {tag=Lbl}
  }
\socket_new_plug:nnn {tagsupport/mylist/taglist}{stop-start-tags}
  {
    \tag_mc_end:% close {tag=Lbl}
    \tag_struct_end:% close {tag=Lbl}
    \tag_struct_begin:n {tag=LBody}
    \tag_struct_begin:n {tag=text-unit}
    \tag_struct_begin:n {tag=text}
  }
\socket_new_plug:nnn {tagsupport/mylist/taglist}{stop-list-tags}
  {
    \tag_struct_end:% close {tag=text}
    \tag_struct_end:% close {tag=text-unit}
    \tag_struct_end:% close {tag=LBody}
    \tag_struct_end:% close {tag=LI}
    \SuspendTagging{#1}
  }
% Wraper socket
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__mylist_start_list_tag:n #1
  {
    \IfDocumentMetadataTF
      {
        \socket_assign_plug:nn {tagsupport/mylist/taglist} {start-list-tags}
        \socket_use:n {tagsupport/mylist/taglist} {#1}
      }
      {}
   }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \__mylist_stop_start_list_tag:
  {
    \IfDocumentMetadataTF
      {
        \socket_assign_plug:nn {tagsupport/mylist/taglist} {stop-start-tags}
        \socket_use:nn {tagsupport/mylist/taglist} { }
      }
      {}
   }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__mylist_stop_list_tag:n #1
  {
    \IfDocumentMetadataTF
      {
        \socket_assign_plug:nn {tagsupport/mylist/taglist} {stop-list-tags}
        \socket_use:nn {tagsupport/mylist/taglist} {#1}
      }
      {}
   }
% Real \item definition
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__mylist_start_item_vii:w [#1]
  {
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__mylist_stop_item_tmp_vii: \__mylist_stop_item_vii:
    \box_clear:N \l_mylist_item_text_vii_box
    \hbox_set_to_wd:Nnw \l_mylist_item_text_vii_box
      {
        \l_mylist_joined_width_vii_dim
        + \l_mylist_labelwidth_vii_dim
        + \l_mylist_labelsep_vii_dim
      }
      % Tagging start
      \__mylist_start_list_tag:n {mylist*}
      \__mylist_fake_make_label_vii:n {#1}
      \__mylist_stop_start_list_tag:
        \begin{minipage}[t]{ \l_mylist_joined_width_vii_dim }
          \dim_set_eq:NN  \parindent \l_mylist_listparindent_vii_dim
          \skip_set_eq:NN \parskip \l_mylist_parsep_vii_skip
          \tl_use:N \l_mylist_fake_item_indent_vii_tl
   }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \__mylist_stop_item_vii:
  {
        \end{minipage}
      \__mylist_stop_list_tag:n {mylist*}% Tagging stop
    \hbox_set_end:
    \int_set:Nn \hbadness { 10000 }
    \box_use_drop:N \l_mylist_item_text_vii_box
    \int_compare:nNnTF
      { \l_mylist_item_column_pos_vii_int } = { \l_mylist_columns_vii_int }
      {
        \par\noindent
        \int_zero:N \l_mylist_item_column_pos_vii_int
      }
      {
        \skip_horizontal:N \l_mylist_columns_sep_vii_dim
      }
  }
% Remove extra \parsep (\itemsep)
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mylist_remove_extra_parsep_vii:
  {
    \int_compare:nNnT
      {
        \int_mod:nn
          { \g_mylist_item_count_all_vii_int } { \l_mylist_columns_vii_int }
      }
      =
      { 0 }
      {
        \para_end:
        \skip_vertical:n { -\l_mylist_itemsep_vii_skip }
        \skip_vertical:N \c_zero_skip
        \int_gzero:N \g_mylist_item_count_all_vii_int
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} Using \texttt{enumerate} first \verb|\item| here. \end{minipage}
  \item \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} Using \texttt{enumerate} second \verb|\item| here. \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{mylist*}[columns=2]
  \item* Using \texttt{mylist*} first \verb|\item| here.
  \item  Using \texttt{mylist*} second \verb|\item| here.
\end{mylist*}

\end{document}


well you need columns=2 to get it horizontal. And you can replace \IfDocumentMetadataTF { \tag_stop: }{ } by \SuspendTagging{mylist} and then resume with `\ResumeTagging{mylist}. And use tagging sockets. See lttagging.dtx in source2e documentation.

@UlrikeFischer Thanks, the \SuspendTagging and \ResumeTagging thing is easy to understand and apply (I've already modified it), but the sockets thing is a different thing and I get lost. I don't know how to compare the correct output that [columns=2] should have and I don't know how to use sockets :( . Could you post an answer that uses sockets and the expected output for [columns=2] for example?

I have not idea what the expected output for columns=2 is, that is your code. I only noticed that with it the items are side by side. You don't have to use tagging sockets if you don't understand them, they only would make the code imho looking a bit nicer.

@UlrikeFischer Sorry, I expressed myself badly here, the output in PDF is what I wanted, I had the impression that when checking with ngpdf I would see the same thing in HTML.

Ah. Well tagging and html derivation is about structure not about look. If you care about the look you would have to add attributes and attach a css that styles the html.

@UlrikeFischer Yes, I have taken a while to read the things associated with tagging, at the end of the day a list is just that and the way it is passed through tagging must have the logic of reading a list (how it looks in HTML is another thing)
